# How to serialize GET params with (jQuery Style) Nested Objects

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-http

I need to send in the following get request via Angular. Upon this request I have a rails server that takes in the param and returns JSON data.

GET request needed:

> http://localhost:8080/clients.json?c[year][]=&c[year][]=2016&c[year][]=2015

Angular code so far:

```
    $http({method: 'GET', url: '/clients.json', params:{???}.success(function(data){
        //angular does something    
    });
```

How would I send in the year parameters in Angular, so that the the server recognizes the c[year][2016] - nested array format? Basically, how would I properly replace the ??? in the code provided?

Comment: you'd need to send it as a json data type llke `?year={"time_one":1479147348, "time_two":1479147348}` and then use `json_decode()` on the GET parameter

Comment: Could you clarify a bit on what you expect the data received by your Rails server to be?

Comment: Try using [$httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike).

Comment: @lucasnadalutti it is expecting the GET request string in the question. Not sure beyond that, as in the rails server you would read that request as `params[c][year]` and it would give you `["2015","2016"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [$httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24httpParamSerializerJQLike):

```
var myUrl = '/clients.json'
var myParams = {c: {year: ["2015", "2016"]}};

$http({
  url: myUrl,
  method: 'GET',
  params: myParams,
  paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike'
});
```

The `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` service is the alternative $http params serializer that follows jQuery's `param()` method logic.

```
JSON:   {"c":{"year":[2014,2015]}}
Encode: c%5Byear%5D%5B%5D=2014&c%5Byear%5D%5B%5D=2015
Decode: c[year][]=2014&c[year][]=2015
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7e2zj510/)

---

> For some reason when I run:
>
> ```
> var myParams = {c: {year: ["","2015","2016"]}};
> var myParamsString = JSON.stringify(myParams);
> var myParamsSerial = $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myParamsSerial);
> ```
>
> the `myParamsSerial` comes back as blank. Any ideas?

Don't stringify the object:

```
 var myParams = {c: {year: ["","2015","2016"]}};
 //DONT stringify
 //var myParamsString = JSON.stringify(myParams);
 //var myParamsSerial = $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myParamsSerial);
 //USE directly
 var myParamsSerial = $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myParams);
```

The params serializer serializes a JavaScript object, not a JSON string.

Comment: Wow, this is great. The paramSerializer option works in the $http call. For some reason when I run: `var myParams = {c: {year: ["","2015","2016"]}};   var myParamsString = JSON.stringify(myParams);  var myParamsSerial = $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myParamsSerial);` - as in your Fiddle -  the myParamsSerial comes back as blank. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You want your server to receive something like this in your GET params:

`{c: {year: ["2015", "2016"]}}`

So the data you send from your Angular app should be exactly in this format. Therefore, this should work:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/clients.json', params: {c: {year: ['2015', '2016']}}.success(function(data){
    //angular does something    
});
```

Comment: That one doesn't work and returns: `http://localhost:8080/clients.json?c=%7B%22year%22:%5B%222015%22,%222016%22%5D%7D`  Looks like it is not putting the params inside the [ ]

Comment: What do you receive in your Rails server? That's what really matters. We should use it to debug, not the URL.